# Determining what indexes should be created in DB2 to optimize the performance of a particular query

Tags: sql, indexing, db2, query-optimization

Let's say I have the query below and it runs for an unacceptably lengthy amount of time... how do I determine from the query what indexes should be created to optimize it?

Does creating indexes from the fields in the SELECT clause help?

Or should I only create indexes based on the fields in the WHERE conditions?

Considering I also have conditions in the CASE clauses, will creating indexes for those fields also help?

```
SELECT A.ALPHA,
       C.BETA, 
       A.KAPPA AS DELTA,
       A.ECHO,
       B.FOXTROT,
       D.GAMMA,
       CASE WHEN (D.THETA IN ('B', '3', '4', 'F', 'D', 'H') OR (D.THETA = 'E' AND D.EPSILON <> '9'))
            THEN D.MU
            WHEN D.THETA = 'E' AND D.EPSILON = '9'
            THEN D.IOTA
            ELSE D.PHI END AS PHI,
       D.CHI,
       CASE WHEN D.THETA LIKE '1%' 
            THEN '1'
            WHEN D.THETA LIKE 'P%' 
            THEN '2'
            WHEN (THETA IN ('B', '3', '4') OR (THETA = 'E' AND PSI <> 'S'))
            THEN '3' 
            WHEN (THETA in ('F', 'D', 'H') OR (THETA = 'E' AND PSI = 'S'))
            THEN '4'
            END AS OMEGA,
       CASE WHEN B.FOXTROT IN (SELECT DISTINCT FOXTROT FROM TAPPLE)
            THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N' END AS ZETA,
       CASE WHEN D.THETA LIKE 'E%' AND D.PSI <> 'S'
            THEN D.TAU
            WHEN D.THETA LIKE 'B%' 
            THEN D.TAU
            WHEN D.THETA LIKE '3%' 
            THEN DATE(D.SIGMA)
            WHEN D.THETA LIKE '4%' 
            THEN DATE(D.SIGMA)
            ELSE NULL END AS RHO
FROM TORANGE A,
     TLIME B,
     (SELECT FOXTROT,BETA FROM TLIME, TLEMON WHERE OMICRON='L' AND ECHO = BETA AND LAMBDA = 'M') C,
     TGRAPE D
WHERE A.ECHO = B.ECHO
  AND B.FOXTROT = C.FOXTROT
  AND B.OMICRON = 'O'
  AND B.FOXTROT = D.FOXTROT
  AND D.THETA IN ('1', 'B', '3', '4', 'E', 'F', 'D', 'H')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DB2 for LUW, you can feed your actual query to the [DB2 Design Advisor](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005144.html), which may suggest indexes and other approaches to improving the expected query performance.

Comment: Edited to indicate that this is a platform specific answer.  @mustaccio may be assuming that the OP is using LUW, although it was not indicated.  Answers to this question are likely to be platform specific, but people seeking answers to this question may come from any DB2 environment.